# Null pointer exception when trying to programmatically perform click on non visible Recycler view item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and I want to perform click on one of its items.

Here is my code:

```
mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(2).itemView.performClick();
```

It works fine when the item is visible, but when it is not visible i'm getting a null pointer exception

also i tried scroll to position before perform click but i got same result

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved my problem with this code

```java
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(17);

search_list.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(17).itemView.performClick();

    }
}, 50);
```

There is a slight delay for the viewholder to be created. Thus if the item is clicked before viewholder is created an NPE would occur

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day.

Comment: Using delay is a very unwise choice, you don't know how much time it takes to draw the view, and when the delay time is less than the drawing time, you will get NPE

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, this is working as intended. When a child View is scrolled out of the boundaries of a RecyclerView, the child View is often reused to display another item for another position in the list, hence you will get a null View for the position that is no longer displayed.

What you can do is implement a getItem() on the RecyclerView.Adapter to retrieve the item for that position. Not sure if that satisfies your requirements though.

Comment: Hey ,thanks man for your response 

I have to issue her that i was trying to prevent recycler view from reusing its item like what we can do with list view but i didn't find a solution for this ,

Comment: and i tried tp perform scroll to position before performclick to make the item visible but it didn't works also

Comment: could plz clarify me how to implement getitem and return the corrent viewholder for position?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use a listener to wait for the drawing to complete,
Then perform the operation you want.

```
    recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // At this point the layout is complete 
            recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Regards!

```
void emulate_userClick()
{
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder xView = xRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(xPosition);

    if( isNull(xView) )
    {   xRecycler.removeOnScrollListener(listener_onScroll);
        xRecycler.addOnScrollListener(listener_onScroll);
        xRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(xPosition);
    }
    else
    {      Objects.requireNonNull( xRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(xPosition)).itemView.performClick();
    }
    
}
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener_onScroll = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
{
    @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        switch (newState) 
        {   case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:  //we reached the target position
                Objects.requireNonNull(xRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(xPosition)).itemView.performClick();
                recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```